# Scrapy: FormRequest from CSV, export in order or with search term

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm new to Python and Scrapy and having some trouble with a simple crawler I've made that uses FormRequest to grab the titles on a search result page.

Basically, the idea is to have a csv filled with search terms and run them through the same form, picking up the titles from the results page, then exporting to a different (or same) csv.

The searching works fine - output is as desired/expected.

The problem is that it exports the titles in the order in which the pages load for scrapy, meaning they are out of order compared to the original csv, and I can't match them back to the lines from the original csv.

Here is my code:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.spider import Spider

class ExampleSpider(Spider):
    name = "examplecsv"
    allowed_domains = ["examplewebsite.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.examplewebsite.com"]

    def parse(self, response):
        with open('addresses.csv') as fp:
            for line in fp:
                yield FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                        formdata={'examplesearchfield':line},
                                        clickdata={'id': 'clickexamplesearch'},
                                        callback=self.parse1)

    def parse1 (self, response):

        for title in response.css('title'):
            yield {

                'title':title.css('title::text').re(r'^[^|]+(?=|)')
            }
```

I have done a bunch of searching on StackOverflow but cant find a problem that matches mine in terms of using FormRequest. I tried setting CONCURRENT_REQUESTS to 1 but that did not help.

Is there a way of either forcing scrapy to wait for each FormRequest to complete before moving on, or to include the input search term along with its output?

My Python knowledge is not advanced, so I am hoping there is a simple tweak to the code that will assist.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest is probably to add the original line number in the request.meta dict and output it when parsing.

Something like this (untested):

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.spider import Spider

class ExampleSpider(Spider):
    name = "examplecsv"
    allowed_domains = ["examplewebsite.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.examplewebsite.com"]

    def parse(self, response):
        with open('addresses.csv') as fp:
            for i, line in enumerate(fp, start=1):
                yield FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                        formdata={'examplesearchfield':line},
                                        clickdata={'id': 'clickexamplesearch'},
                                        callback=self.parse1,
                                        meta={'lineno': i})

    def parse1 (self, response):

        for title in response.css('title'):
            yield {

                'title':title.css('title::text').re(r'^[^|]+(?=|)'),
                'lineno': response.meta['lineno']
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the CSV data to your request and include it in your final yield.
This will create an output that wouldn't need "matching them back together".

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.spider import Spider

class ExampleSpider(Spider):
    name = "examplecsv"
    allowed_domains = ["examplewebsite.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.examplewebsite.com"]

    def parse(self, response):
        with open('addresses.csv') as fp:
            for line in fp:
                yield FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                        formdata={'examplesearchfield':line},
                                        clickdata={'id': 'clickexamplesearch'},
                                        meta={'line' : line },
                                        callback=self.parse1)

    def parse1 (self, response):

        for title in response.css('title'):
            yield {
                'line' : response.meta.get('line')
                'title':title.css('title::text').re(r'^[^|]+(?=|)')
            }
```